# Generating a unique id for storing in cache

Tags: java, caching, key-value

I am maintaining a cache with a unique id and the corresponding value, to be retrieved in say class Y. This unique id is something which class Y is aware of, to retrieve. The cache values are configured to expire in 10 minutes.

The solution I could think of is to generate an incremental value as the uniquq id. For each new entry, there will be a new id (+1). But then this will be a value which would never get reset - although the the value for the particular cache element would not be required after 10 minutes

*How best to generate this unique id?*

Comment: After ten minutes *only* cache is no more needed, or every instance of class Y previously cached is also unneeded?

Comment: every instance of class Y previously cached is also unneeded

Comment: It is very unclear what you actually try to achieve. What kind of data you are caching? How do you know the ID to retrieve the value? Why you like to reset the ID value, if it needs to be unique? Double check whether you are really asking the right question at all. See: XYProblem.

Answer (score 2):

When you adding 1 you will need to take care about thread safety too.
Better use sth like `java.util.UUID`
and don't care about any resetting...

But to tell the truth the cache key should be created from cache content - (ex. hash function based on request params) so same params will get same cache ky - hence you will retrieve value from cache...